# Is prayer heard in all places of song?

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, tractate-brachot

Berachos 6a:

> תַּנְיָא, אַבָּא בִּנְיָמִין אוֹמֵר: אֵין תְּפִלָּה שֶׁל אָדָם נִשְׁמַעַת אֶלָּא בְּבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״לִשְׁמֹעַ אֶל הָרִנָּה וְאֶל הַתְּפִלָּה״. בִּמְקוֹם רִנָּה — שָׁם תְּהֵא תְּפִלָּה.
>
> It was taught in a Braisa: Abba Binyamin said, "A person's prayer is only heard in a shul, as it says, 'To hear the song and the prayer' – in the place of song, there should prayer be.

As Rashi explains,

> במקום רנה – בבהכ"נ ששם אומרים הצבור שירות ותשבחות בנעימת קול ערב:
>
> "In the place of song" – in a shul, where the congregation says there songs and praises in a sweet voice.

There are other such places where we, as a community, gather to sing Hashem's praises, such as a wedding hall. Is prayer heard in these places as well? If not, why is a shul special in this regard?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53317705#53317705

Comment: Did wedding halls exist back then? Seems unlikely

Comment: @DoubleAA Who says they have to have existed back then? Apply the Gemara to nowadays.